# How can we transfer id data with node index.js?id=1

Tags: node.js

How can we transfer id data with node?

node index.js?id=1

```
 var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    
    app.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
        res.send('id: ' + req.params.id);
        console.log(req.params.id);
    });
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In nodejs.org there's a piece of documentation where the functionality you desire is explained in a clear and simple way (https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/clients/how-to-access-query-string-parameters/).

Basically, what you are using in **the code you showed returns the part of the path** where you use the ":[name]" (a subdirectory).
What you actually want to get are the **query string parameters** by using **url.parse(req.url,true).query** which **returns an object with a set of key:value pairs with the name of each parameter and respective value**.
Be aware that to use that line of code you'll need at least to **require the url module**.

I hope I made myself clear and that my answer helps you!